# Obten la palabra en mayuscula de una String

Tags: java

Me gustaria saber como obtener la palabra en mayuscula de la siguiente string

String palabra = ""

String palabra = ""

En este caso necesito una nueva String con HOLA y no me sirve cortar la string porque pueden variar las posiciones

Comment: Tu pregunta carece de sentido, puedes editarla para aclarar lo que pides?

Comment: Entiendo que quieres buscar una palabra en una frase y pasar sólo esa palabra a mayúsculas???

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar el metodo `.toUpperCase();` que te permite convertir cualquier string (Este o no este en Mayusculas) a que todas esten en Mayusculas.

```
String str = "Hola Mundo!";
System.out.println(str.toUpperCase()); //Convierte a:  "HOLA MUNDO!"
```

Espero te sirva, Saludos!

Comment: Aun estando muy mal explicado la pregunta, creo que el usuario lo que busca es de un string cualquiera ("Me GUSTARIA ir a la playa") sacar la palabra que esta en mayusculas("GUSTARIA") y no transformar todas a mayusculas...

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer un método `String` `getLetrasMayusculas(String palabra)`, y en este método retornar las letras mayusculas tengan la `String palabra`. Puedes iterar cada letra en `palabra` y utilizar `java.lang.Character.isUpperCase` para ir llenando tu retorno.

Saludos